# Android animated-rotate attributes not working

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to make custom animated progressBar only with xml.

I made layer-list with circles, but when i use tag animated-rotate for all circles with different attributes, they are still doing the same thing.

How can i make different rotating animation for every item in this list?

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item android:id="@+id/first">
        <animated-rotate
            android:duration="2000"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:repeatCount="1"
            android:toDegrees="-360">
            <shape
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:innerRadius="100dp"
                android:shape="oval">
                <padding
                    android:bottom="3dp"
                    android:left="3dp"
                    android:right="3dp"
                    android:top="3dp" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:dashWidth="60dp"
                    android:dashGap="60dp" />
                <size
                    android:width="150dp"
                    android:height="150dp" />
            </shape>
        </animated-rotate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <animated-rotate
            android:duration="300"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:repeatCount="infinite"
            android:toDegrees="360">
            <shape
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:innerRadius="100dp"
                android:shape="oval">
                <padding
                    android:bottom="3dp"
                    android:left="3dp"
                    android:right="3dp"
                    android:top="3dp" />

                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/colorSecondary"
                    android:dashWidth="50dp"
                    android:dashGap="50dp" />
            </shape>
        </animated-rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to create one file with the animation. And inside of your code, use a thread to set a delay between when the animations start.

For example,

```
Thread t = new Thread(){  
    public void run(){  
        t.sleep(500);
        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(StartActivity.this, R.anim.rotate);
        view.startAnimation(rotation);

        t.sleep(500);
        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(StartActivity.this, R.anim.rotate);
        view2.startAnimation(rotation);

        t.sleep(500):
        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(StartActivity.this, R.anim.rotate);
        view3.startAnimation(rotation);
        ..... (This would go on until you started the animation for all the circles)
    }  
}
t.start();
```